# Rfc2898DeriveBytes password matches with string and not with byte[]

Tags: c#, authentication, hash, passwords

I am trying to create an authentication server with login and password credentials and I used [this tutorial](http://csharptest.net/470/another-example-of-how-to-store-a-salted-password-hash/) that gave me the following `PasswordHash` class. This works great when I use the `Verify` method with a string but I do not want to send the password unencrypted through UDP for security reasons but when I test the hashes directly by feeding it the byte array it returns false (as shown below the class).

```
public sealed class PasswordHash
{
    const int SaltSize = 16, HashSize = 20, HashIter = 10000;
    readonly byte[] _salt, _hash;

    private PasswordHash() { }

    public PasswordHash(string password)
    {
        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(_salt = new byte[SaltSize]);
        _hash = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, HashIter).GetBytes(HashSize);
    }
    public PasswordHash(byte[] hashBytes)
    {
        Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, _salt = new byte[SaltSize], 0, SaltSize);
        Array.Copy(hashBytes, SaltSize, _hash = new byte[HashSize], 0, HashSize);
    }
    public PasswordHash(byte[] salt, byte[] hash)
    {
        Array.Copy(salt, 0, _salt = new byte[SaltSize], 0, SaltSize);
        Array.Copy(hash, 0, _hash = new byte[HashSize], 0, HashSize);
    }
    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        byte[] hashBytes = new byte[SaltSize + HashSize];
        Array.Copy(_salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, SaltSize);
        Array.Copy(_hash, 0, hashBytes, SaltSize, HashSize);
        return hashBytes;
    }
    public byte[] Salt { get { return (byte[])_salt.Clone(); } }
    public byte[] Hash { get { return (byte[])_hash.Clone(); } }
    public bool Verify(string password)
    {
        byte[] test = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, HashIter).GetBytes(HashSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < HashSize; i++)
            if (test[i] != _hash[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public bool Verify(byte[] passwordHash) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < HashSize; i++)
            if (passwordHash[i] != _hash[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tested it by using:

```
bool test = new PasswordHash("test123").Verify("test123"); //TRUE
bool test2 = new PasswordHash("test123").Verify(newPasswordHash("test123").ToArray()); //FALSE
```

So as Nissim pointed out, they don't match because the salt is randomly generated every time I call `new PasswordHash().` Is there anyway to bypass the salt that's added to the byte[]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call the PasswordHash's constructor it creates a new salt, hence in the following example:

```
byte[] pass1 = new HashPassword("abc").ToArray();
byte[] pass2 = new HashPassword("abc").ToArray();
```

pass1 is different than pass2

Comment: Oh! So there is no way of verifying two hashes bypassing the salt?

Comment: You can add a constructor to the `HashPassword` class which will get the salt as parameter: `public PasswordHash(string password, byte[] salt)
    {
        _salt = (byte[])salt.Clone();
        _hash = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, HashIter).GetBytes(HashSize);
    }`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Going to test it later.